# jquery tabs with tab navigations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I want to make a content box with jquery tabs with a tab navigation for many tab contents, such as for more than 10 tab contents. The problem is that jquery UI does not provide built in tab navigation for large tab number and the "scrollable tabs for jquery plugin" at google code, https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-scrollable-tabs/, looks very slow and inefficient for large volumes about more than 50 pages. If the user tries to read the 1st and the 40th page, it will take more than 30 sec. to navigate for clicking the arrows.

So, I made a tab content box with only 5 tabs including selected shown and with a tab navigation of input text box selecting specific pages and next and previous with the first and the last page tab navigation buttons. (If you put regular jquery UI tab with more than 20-30 tabs it will mess up appearance and css.)

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="TabbedPageNavi">
    <li>Page
        <input id="pageNumber" type="text" value="01" style="width:30px;" />
    </li>
    <li><a class="previous" href="#">&laquo;&nbsp;Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nexttab" href="#">Next&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
    </li>
    <li class="copyTab">2013&nbsp;&copy;John3825&nbsp;blog</li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-spacer"></div>
<div id="tab-contents">
    <div id="tabs-1">
```

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/john3825/anh7c/embedded/result/

What is the best possible way to manage the large numbers of content tabs with navigation? Please tell me a example or correct problems.

I also want to make the tab content box fit within 350px width x 1000px height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the best possible way is concerned,there are many of them.One suggestion would be using `iFrames.`

> The Result would be quite like this : [DEMO](http://tsb.catalystdigitalpartners.com/real-tennis-and-lawn-tennis-a-conversation-starter/)

Or either your approach is quite scalable and is old-school which is good thing in reference of compatibility and usability. Now the other requirement goes like this. You set the `width:350px;` and the `height:1000px` for the content-tab like this.

> Working Fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xeemez/anh7c/2/)

**Code:**

```
#tab-content{

height: 1000px !important;
width:350px;
background-color:darkgrey;
border:2px ridge black;

}
```

Comment: iFrame tabs will probably work but slow as flash swf tabs and may not good for usability. I want to use jquery or possibly javascript only for usability and accessibility because simple css and javascript tabs can be used on any platforms.  Problem of using jquery is that if the site uses a CMS or a template engine, it may restrict some functions. Also, adding iFrame contents will result in difficulty of reading by machines with SEO manners. The site should made by plain text or clear HTML or other to make user friendly and easily find the content user want. It is a rule on User accessibility.

Comment: So, I want to make a plain jquery or javascript content box with tab navigation. Please tell me the best possible way to make a content tab box with a tab navigation.

Comment: For that you are using right approach.Plain SHTML with jQuery.

Comment: How to combine fx toggle option for jquery ui tabs with activate: function () on the same select event?

Comment: from what I understood of your question you can have selector represented as "this" to achieve it.If I am misunderstood than you have to elaborate it more or ask another question with specified code in it.